# Problem in writing Haskell Codes in Minted Package in Texstudio

Tags: texstudio, minted, code, pygments

I used this

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{haskell}
--type Stack a = [a]  
--push :: Stack a -> a -> Stack a
--push xs x = x:xs

--pop :: Stack a -> (a, Stack a)
--pop [] = error "Empty List"
--pop (x:xs) = (x, xs)

data Stack a = Stack [a]
instance Show a => Show (Stack a) where
show (Stack [a]) = show [a]
    
push :: Stack a -> a -> Stack a
    push (Stack xs) x = Stack (x:xs)
    
pop :: Stack a -> (a,Stack a)
pop (Stack xs) 
    | null xs = error "Empty List"
    |  otherwise = (head xs, Stack xs) 
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

It was showing me the error that

```
line 3: Package minted Error: You must invoke LaTeX with the -shell-escape flag. \begin
line 3: Emergency stop. \begin{document}
      : shell escape is disabled, so I can only detect \ifwindows.
```

Then I used the command `-shell-escape` in commands section of `configure texstudio' in the pdflatex section like this

```
pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape %.tex
```

Then it was showing me this error

```
line 35: Package minted Error: You must have `pygmentize' installed to use this package. \begin{document}
```

Then I installed pygments by running the command

```
pip3 install pygments
```

Here is the log file
I am giving the link of the [Log File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YtHs8cbtUKcCBc3AzASImsoyjqWtldUJ/view?usp=sharing)

How to finally get over all of this. And start writing haskell code in using minted.
For reference I use windows 11 and texstudio.

Comment: your document runs without error and [produces this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNLni.png)  it is hard to see the errors you got as you only showed the (more or less useless) summary from your editor rather than the actual error in the log file (which would show which command was undefined) however I would start by deleting the cache which should be a folder named `_minted-<your file name>`  and get minted to re-create it now everything is installed.

Comment: I have added the log file see now. And tell me the solution in full details as i dont know much about these stuffs

Comment: Now i added the log file.

Comment: you have `Package: fancyvrb 2021/10/15 v3.9 verbatim text (tvz,hv)` and I have `Package: fancyvrb 2021/11/24\nobreakspace {} 4.1a\nobreakspace {}verbatim text `  your error is related to a command `\FV@PYG ` so fancyverb related. Update your tex system with `tlmgr` to pull in the latest updates.

Comment: How to do that...and i have removd all the packages except mined...you can check the log file

Comment: minted relies on fancyverb. Given that you are using a version released in October and there was another release in November I assume there was a bug introduced that got fixed.  I don't have windows texlive but I assume it's same as on other platforms, you should be able to type `tlmgr update --all` to update everything (or use the graphical version of tlmgr which will have a similar menu option)